# How to create component inside other component in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I need to split one complicated component into two or more simplier using directives in template.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way how to implement this.

**MainComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService1 } from '../../providers/myService1/myService1';
import { MyCmp1 } from '../../components/myCmp1/myCmp1';

@Component({
   templateUrl: 'build/pages/mainComponent/mainComponent.html',
   providers: [
      MyService1
   ],
   directives: [
      MyCmp1
   ],
   //pipes: [ ... ] // Pipes which you are using
})
export class MainComponent {
   main: any;

   constructor() {
      this.load();
   }

   load(): void {
       MyService1.loadData()
          .then((response) => {
               main.data1 = response;
          });
   }

   onShowMe(data): void {
       alert(data);
   }
}
```

**MainComponent.html**

```
<div class="main-component">
   <h1>Main Component</h1>
   <my-cmp-1 [data1]="main?.data1" (onShowMe)="onShowMe($event)"></my-cmp-1>
</div>
```

---

**MyCmp1.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
   selector: 'my-cmp-1',
   templateUrl: 'build/components/myCmp1/myCmp1.html'
})

export class MyCmp1 {
   @Input() data1: any;
   @Output() onShowMe = new EventEmitter();

   showMe(event: Event, data: any): void {
      event.preventDefault(); // If you are using <a> or etc.
      this.onShowMe.emit(data);
   }
}
```

**MyCmp1.html**

```
<h3>My Component 1</h3>
<a href="" (click)="showMe($event, 'message from MyCmp1')">Show Me</a>
```